# Use residue formula to calculate integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for $n\geq 1$, $$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{{(1+x^2)}^{n+1}}=\frac{1 \cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}\cdot\pi$$

My approach: I constructed a semi-circle on the upper half plane, where R>1. I think the order of pole at $z=i$ is $n+1$, because $\frac{1}{(z-i)^{n+1}}=(z+i)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{1+z^2})^{n+1}$ is holomorphic and never goes to zero in some neighborhood of $z=i$.
Then I used the formula,
$res_i f=\lim_{z \to i} \frac{1}{n!}(\frac{d}{dz})^n(z+i)^{-(n+1)}$. Then I plgged into $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=2\pi ires_i f$. Here obviously, on the upper circle contour, the integration vanishes. And when I calculate it, the result I get is far from the answer above.

Where could I possibly do wrong?

Comment: @JackLeGrüß In the formula you have $(z-i)^{n+1} \frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}$, which simplifies to  $\dfrac{1}{(z+i)^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was your result? Following your post, I would expect that you arrived at
$$
2 \pi i \,\textrm{Res}(f,i) =\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+n)}{n! 2^{2n}} \pi,
$$

which is the correct result, and is equivalent to the proposed formula. Maybe you got the right result and did not notice!

Comment: Obviously, I didn't notice it haha. Thank you so much.